# Can not archive new React Native iOS project (WasmCodeManager, PhaseScriptExecution)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I can not archive a brand new React Native (0.68.2) iOS project using TypeScript.

#### What I did

1. Created a new project and installed CocoaPods

   ```
   npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
   ```
2. Opened workspace with XCode, checked "Automatically manage signing" and selected my team
3. Selected "Any iOS Device (arm64)"
4. Xcode > Product > Archive

After 1 minute I run into this issue:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: WasmCodeManager::Commit: Cannot make pre-reserved region writable Allocation failed - process out of memory

../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh: line 164: 78153 Abort trap: 6 "$NODE_BINARY" $NODE_ARGS "$CLI_PATH" $BUNDLE_COMMAND $CONFIG_ARG --entry-file "$ENTRY_FILE" --platform "$BUNDLE_PLATFORM" --dev $DEV --reset-cache --bundle-output "$BUNDLE_FILE" --assets-dest "$DEST" $EXTRA_ARGS $EXTRA_PACKAGER_ARGS
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

#### What I'm using

- MacBook Pro (2021)
- M1 Max 32 GB
- macOS 12.4
- XCode 13.4
- Node.js 14.18.1
- Terminal with Rosetta

#### What I already tried

- reinstalling Ruby and rvm
- reinstalling node
- reinstalling CocoaPods
- creating another brand new project